# Where do I go wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

**Suppose $X,Y$ are independent** Uniform$(0,1)$ **random variables. Find the probability $P(Y\geq X\mid Y\geq\dfrac{1}{2})$.**

Please note that I know the correct answer and that I have arrived at the correct answer both geometrically and analytically. So that means I solved the problem, which happens to be an easy one. But, I was investigating another method and got a different answer, which, undoubtedly, was wrong. Here is my method:

$$P(Y\geq X\mid Y\geq\frac{1}{2})=\frac{P(Y\geq X,Y\geq\frac {1}{2})}{P(Y\geq\frac{1}{2})}=\dfrac {P(Y\geq \max\{X,\dfrac{1}{2}\})}{\dfrac{1}{2}}.$$
The numerator is to be worked with now. $$P(Y\geq \max\{X,\frac{1}{2}\})=P(Y\geq X\mid X\geq0.5)P(X\geq0.5)+P(Y\geq0.5\mid X\leq0.5)P(X\leq0.5)=P(Y\geq X\mid X\geq0.5)(0.5)+(0.5)(0.5)$$

**Now we evaluate** $$P(Y\geq X\mid X\geq0.5)=\int_{0.5}^1 \!P(Y\geq k\mid X=k)f_X(k)\,\mathrm{d}k=\int_{0.5}^1\!(1-k)\,\mathrm{d}k=\frac{1}{8}$$

So our final answer turns out to be $$\frac{\dfrac{1}{8}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{5}{8}$$

while the correct answer is $\dfrac{3}{4}$.

Comment: The problem is here. Consider $Z=X|X>0.5$. We have to evaluate $P(Y\ge X|X>0.5)$ this is equivalent to $\int\limits_{0.5}^1 P(Y\ge k|Z=k)f_{_Z}(k)\,dk$.

Comment: Hmm, just as I guessed. In dealing with conditional probabilities, maybe it is more prudent to condition on equalities and not inequalities. Indeed, I got the correct answer in three different ways, and one of them included conditioning on $X=k$, and that yielded the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral calculates $P(Y \geq X \geq 0.5)$, not $P(Y \geq X| X \geq 0.5)$.

Comment: Indeed true. In fact, one of my correct solutions uses this.